# Autoplay video JQuery when video is in center of my screen

Tags: jquery, video

i need your help.
I want to launch my video when the video is around in a center of my screen , and put in pause when its around out of  the screen
How i can do this?
Actually, i have just this code :

```
<%= video_tag 'Garden.mp4', :height =>"350px", :class => "video", :controls => true, :muted => true, :autoplay => true%>
```

And on my js file, i have this following code : Play / Stop when mouseenter / mouseover.

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () { this.play(); },
    mouseleave: function () { this.pause(); }
}, '.video');
```

Thanks to help me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Following code Work.
Between, 33% top and down, your video will play.

```
$(window).scroll(function(e)
  {
    var offsetRange = $(window).height() / 3,
        offsetTop = $(window).scrollTop() + offsetRange + $("#header").outerHeight(true),
        offsetBottom = offsetTop + offsetRange;

    $(".video").each(function () { 
      var y1 = $(this).offset().top;
      var y2 = offsetTop;
      if (y1 + $(this).outerHeight(true) < y2 || y1 > offsetBottom) {
        this.pause(); 
      } else {
        this.play();
      }
    });
});
```